# What do you call whipped cream with gelatin?

Tags: word-request

I had some heavy cream left that I didn't want to go to waste. I whipped it, mixed it with sugar, honey, some dissolved gelatin and put it into a fridge (just to see what happens). I got some mousse-like dessert. I'm sure there's a special term for what I got. What term?

When flavored with red currant and made into a cake, it may look like this

[image]

[image]

Comment: What do people normally do with this stuff? Is it put on toast or what?

Comment: Yuk. Just yuk. Why did you do this?

Comment: "I'm sure there's a special term for what I got"  Why?  Is there a special term in your language?

Comment: Anyway, my nan used to make "milk jelly" with strawberry jelly and milk. So I suppose "cream jelly"  would work. TBH I don't know if that was a recipe that she invented herself - like her "mooncakes" for a space obsessed five-year-old.

Comment: It reminds me of this stuff called 'Instant Whip' which was a stand-by in my student days. Not to be confused with a US product of a similar name.

Comment: @JamesK **Everyone's** nan made milk jelly!

Comment: Sounds a bit like a _syllabub_, though that didn't include jelly.

Comment: @ColinFine - is that American 'jelly', or British? There is a difference.

Comment: I'm well aware of that, @MichaelHarvey. I took it that James K was already using British "jelly" - I didn't check his provenance at that time, but the use of "nan" seemed pretty diagnostic - so I didn't feel a need to translate it into American.

Comment: @ColinFine - ah OK.  Incidentally, maybe I'm stuffy, but I had a 'grandmother'...

Comment: I had a "gran'ma" until she died.

Comment: @ColinFine - OH, I addressed mine as 'Nanny' but she was my grandmother. I am taken aback to see tabloid press stories which say things like 'Mary Smith, aged 49, a nan, was fined £40 for drunkenness'.

Comment: You have [the ingredients for **a revised version of** ***panna cotta***](https://www.allrecipes.com/recipe/72567/panna-cotta/), you just skipped the part where you cook the cream before adding the cooled down gelatin.

Comment: Shouldn't this be asked on [cooking.se] instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a concoction you invented... call it what you like!

It has certain similarities to milk jelly (BrE) made by mixing (flavoured) gelatine with milk.  And also to blancmange (made with milk/almondmilk, cream, cornflour and gelatine and flavourings)  There are lots of variations in the recipes for blancmange.

It's not a syllabub or posset or junket, as these involve curdled milk, not milk thickened with gelatine. Nor is it a yoghurt, as that is thickened by a bacterial fermentation, nor mousse, which uses egg as a thickener.

Comment: There are some commercial yoghourt which do contain gelatine, as vegetarians know well. Sometimes the same brand will have pots with and without gelatine.

Comment: Isn't it mousse?

Comment: indeed, but you would say that gelatine is added to yoghurt, to improve texture etc. It's not essential.

Comment: No. mousse is thickened with egg

Comment: Traditionally, 'gelatine' is the UK spelling, and 'gelatin' the American, but many UK people are careless about that distinction. Something that mildly annoys my pharmacist partner is not only the lazy use of 'adrenalin' in fiction as a signifier for excitement but the confusion by many between 'adrenaline' (the hormone also called  epinephrine), 'Adrenalin' (the US-only proprietary formulation), and 'adrenalin' (what's that?).

Answer (score 2):

You have made [stabilized whipped cream](https://www.google.com/search?q=stabilized%20whipped%20cream).